# Jsp file throw internal server 500 error sometimes

Tags: java, javascript, apache, jsp

I am new to JSP the following is my jsp file

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
<%= System.getProperties().getProperty(java.version) %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I get the following error when the above jsp file ran on APACHE SERVER

```
Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
java.version cannot be resolved to a type
1: <HTML>
2: <BODY>
3: Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
4: <%= System.getProperties().getProperty(java.version) %>
5: </BODY>
6: </HTML>
```

The error message is infrequent once in 10 times I refresh the I get the error.The other 9 times I get the output of all system properties even if I need only the java.version property of the system.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: How did it display all of the System Properties if it was a Error in the firs place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= System.getProperties().getProperty(java.version) %>
```

replace it with

```
<%= System.getProperties().getProperty("java.version") %>
```

The required input to `getProperty()` method is of `String` type and you need to pass `String` with double quotes.

Comment: Thank You it worked well. How did it display all of the System Properties if it was a Error in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

add this with your body

```
<%= System.getProperties().getProperty("java.version") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= System.getProperties().getProperty("java.version") %> //was missing ""
```